# Possible Chrome Extension Dev with Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, google-chrome-extension, sinatra

I am trying to make a Chrome extension that shows information on the screen when a new tab is added, like Momentum and loads of other extensions. I was wondering if it was possible to run a Ruby Sinatra app in that window or if I would have to use JavaScript or some other language.

Comment: You can't run Ruby code in the browser, but with Sinatra you could serve a html page that is loaded by the extension. Although I think usually extensions just use Javascript

Answer (score 0):

A chrome extension can only run javascript, but you could write a sinatra app and have the javascript access it.

Comment: How would I go about doing that, redirecting?